# Share an Interface

Tags: java, interface, jar, driver

I am writing a Java application that will load third party "drivers". I intend to develop an interface that will define the required methods that the "driver" must implement in order to work within the application.

The intent is for the "driver" to be contained within a jar file. Then third party "driver" developers will be required to implement the interface.

As I'm trying to figure this out, I moved the "driver" code to a jar and found that I am having trouble since I have the interface defined in both the main application and in the jar file.

Is there a recommended way to implement this approach, or am I headed the wrong way?

j

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You basically define the interface once, e.g. in an API jar. This jar is then used by the main application as well as the driver.

The driver library would then have this API jar as a dependency that is provided by the main application.

In terms of Maven the dependency would have scope `provided` or `compile` for the library.

Note that you should avoid having the same class twice in different libraries since those will most likely lead to class loading problems, class cast exceptions etc. (unless there's some class loader scoping that isolates applications, like most application servers do).

Comment: +1 this is the right answer. An excellent and well-known example of this design is `servlet-api.jar`, which comes with every copy of Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Since the interface is part of the API / library you're providing, you should have the interface there and the third parties should import your API (from your jar) and implement the appropriate interface, like how the Java API provides a SQL interface, but not an actual implementation, and MySQL implements the Java API interface.  If your interface for the driver has use outside your application, you could pack it as a separate jar, but if it's really only useful for interaction with your library, it should be packed with the rest of the library.

Comment: The interface defines how the main application talks to the driver. I was thinking I could "add" drivers to the application dynamically, and the application would be able to interact with the driver due to the interface definition.

Comment: What about having several driver jars that all contain that interface? In that case you'd have multiple copies of that interface which most likely will lead to problems.

Comment: That's exactly what I discovered.

Comment: @Thomas why would separate APIs implement the exact same interface that wasn't part of the Java API?  They should at least be in different packages.  If they really want to package the drivers as separate jars, then they should have a "common" jar.

Comment: and libraries from third parties implementing the API interface should use the interface from the API jar.

Comment: @Kevin That's exactly the point. Since the main application also needs that interface it should be provided by that main application, be it in a separate jar or not. The driver needs it at compile time but it should not be present inside the driver jar. Think of multiple parties providing driver jars. In that case you don't know how many drivers the main application will use and even in case there are none the main application needs to know that interface.

Comment: @Kevin Btw, I was refering to `it needs to be in the driver jar` which is wrong here. If the interface was an _internal_ part of the driver the main application might just ignore it but here we have an interface for the communication _between_ the main application and the driver and thus is part of both.

Comment: OK, I think I misunderstood the situation.  I thought he was implementing a program for which he needed to use a particular (separate) API.  But he's actually implementing the meat of the API?

Comment: Yes, I want to define the API. That way I control the implementation of the drivers. I am using an interface in it's purist form, I just wasn't sure how to apply it to my situation.

Answer (score -1):

If you'e actually moved the interface you need to rebuild both jars. If you've copied it then you'll need to give one a different package name

Comment: If you have two interfaces with different package names they'll be different classes and you'd get `ClassCastException`s when you try to cast the driver that implements interface A to interface B within the main application.

Comment: @Thomas Hmmm, don't think you quite appreciated my comment.

Comment: @DaveRIz it doesn't really answer the question which is how to deal with a common interface that both the application and the driver need to use. It's not about rebuilding the jar or creating two distinct interfaces.